# Need help understanding/installing a service from GitHub via Composer

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I am trying to install a service from GitHub via Composer but I am having trouble understanding and debugging since the installation of the service (PrintNode-PHP) does not work.

I have a web-hotel via UnoEuro where I have installed Composer. This seems to have worked fine.

On GitHub there is a service that I want to install on my web-hotel, so I have connected to my web-hotel and folder where I want to install via Terminal/SSH (Mac) and installed the service: https://github.com/PrintNode/PrintNode-PHP

I installed the service: `php composer.phar require PrintNode/printnode-php:dev-master`

And get this (successful) result:

```
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing printnode/printnode-php (dev-master 960acab): Cloning 960acabca3
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Now I am trying the examples and this is where errors occur.
I am trying to do this example: https://github.com/PrintNode/PrintNode-PHP/blob/master/examples/example-1-submitting-a-printjob.php

However I get an error that a file (credentials.php) is not found - when using Composer I thought that the vendor-installation made sure that all dependant files was installed. Error can be seen here: http://maxie.dk/labels/example-1-submitting-a-printjob.php

When looking in the folder I can see that I have the credentials.php file although located in src/PrintNode/credentials.php. So I have tried to update the path in the above PHP-file, but still same error:

```
Warning: include(credentials.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/maxie.dk/public_html/labels/example-1-submitting-a-printjob.php on line 8
```

So the question is: what am I doing wrong here? what am I missing that results in me not being able to install and use PrintNode service from Composer without errors?

I hope someone can guide me so I can get this to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apparently there's instructions on the examples readme that's not on the main readme. https://github.com/PrintNode/PrintNode-PHP/blob/960acabca3c0d976bbd92bf0d6490a1fe5df7496/examples/README.md Note the Prerequesites section

Comment: @aynber - I see. I tried installing this and now I do not get that error no more. Now it looks to be errors within the service. Specifically related to API-credentials. Now I know that this has nothing to do with the above, but any help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the repository you see that there is a template `credentials.php.dist`, but not a credentials.php. You will have to copy this file as `credentials.php` and replace the API-Key in there with a valid one.